# Filling in a 2D array or constructing a grid with predetermined numbers?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there was a way to construct a grid or 2D array with predetermined numbers.  Specifically, problem 11 of project Euler presents the following 20x20 grid:

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

And I'm trying to recreate it in code.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to recreate the array? At runtime? Or hardcoded? Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
int a[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3},
                { 4, 5, 6},
                { 7, 8, 9} };
```

You're actually allowed to flatten the brace initializer out into a single run of numbers, but it's nice to be clear. In C99 and C++11 you can also have extraneous trailing commas.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to manually add in the commas?

Comment: @BobJohn: write a script to generate the code for you? That's doable with a single line of shell scripting.

Comment: … or a single replace expression in a reasonably powerful text editor.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about writing a script or replace expression to do this.  Any tips?

Comment: @BobJohn: In your editor, look for a feature called "search and replace" and replace `" "` by `", "`. In Bash, I'd use a `for` loop maybe.